# How to force foucus on child window until it's closed

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I make a child form have forced focus so that you can't do anything with the parent form until it's closed?

Preferably like this: http://youtu.be/WJWnYBOwQzU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ShowDialog` rather than just `Show`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx